# Extra characters in reading emails from imap_search()

Tags: php, mysql, imap

I've code that scans my inbox & find email address which got delivery failure. What I need to do is if these email addresses match already existing email addresses in Database, it should do the stuff.
When I get output of email addresses from my inbox, it contains some extra characters which I can not get rid of.
Here's my code:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';
$hostname = "XXXXXX";
$inbox = imap_open($hostname, 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX');
if ($inbox) 
{
function getBetween($message,$start,$end){
    $temp= substr($message, 0, strpos($message, $end));
    return substr($temp, strpos($temp, $start));
}

$date = date( "d-M-Y", strToTime( "-1 days" ));
$email=imap_search($inbox, 'SUBJECT "Mail delivery failed" SINCE "'.$date.'"',
       SE_UID);

foreach($email as $email_number) {
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1);    
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    $start = "The following address(es) failed:";
    $end = "No Such User Here";
    $newcontent = getBetween($message,$start,$end);
    $final=str_replace("$start","","$newcontent");
    $array=explode(' ',$final);

    foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value;
    $data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invitations WHERE
            email_invited='".$value."'"));
    if($data[0] != NULL){
    mysql_query("update invitations set invalid_email=1,success=0 where
                 email_invited='".$value."' limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
}
}
```

If you want to look at the output of `echo $value` under `foreach($array as $value)`, it's exactly like below:

```
hello@test.com hello@test.com hello@test.com hello@test.com hello@test.com soni.shanil@test.com sonishanil19@test.com
```

It seems due to these spaces, it's not able to search through the query. I also tried doing `str_replace(" ","","$final")`, but that didn't work as well.
Any help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking all over, I managed to get it was trim() function that I missed. I used it & everything worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, what a nice SQL injection. **Please**, consider using parametrized queries. It's 2014 and this was was already broken ten years ago. Your application is vulnerable and someone will hack you through that.

Comment: Yes it's on the way, will soon implement it.